# Error: This project cannot be added because it does not produce a jar file using an Ant script

Tags: jsf, testing, netbeans, ant, jsfunit

I created a test project using JSFUnit 1.3 in Netbeans 7.3. I want to test the classes and pages of another project so I added it by right-clicking, properties, libraries, add project. I selected the project and click OK but I get this error. "This project cannot be added because it does not produce a jar file using an Ant script".

Both projects were created as Java Web -> Web Application -> Components(JSF 2.1)